# wpf nested popups

Tags: wpf, popup, nested

I'm developing a custom control which has a button that opens a popup.
When that popup contains another instance of my custom control (which also has a button that opens another popup, e.g. a calendar) some problems occur.
The second (nested) popup won't act as suspected. Clicks don't work, won't close, when parent popup is closed.
Are there any specific best practices when using nested popups?

Comment: We are doing basically the same thing - we have buttons that open popups, which sometimes contain buttons that open nested popups.  If both popups have StaysOpen="false", clicks/touches stop working and the nested popup won't close when you click inside the parent popup.  Sometimes our app completely stops processing clicks/touches as well.  It works if the parent popup has StaysOpen="true" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. We have a custom `DropDownSubsetSelector` control in our wpf controls library. This control has a `Popup` in its control template with `StaysOpen="False"`. Today I had to put this control on a custom view that is located inside wpf's `Popup` control with `StaysOpen="False"` and was wondered of this unexpected nested `Popup`s behaviour. My workaround for this issue was to inspect Microsoft's source code of a classical `ComboBox` control. You can find it here [Combobox Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs). As you can see its behaviour on a `Popup` control is exactly the same you expect from `Popup` being located on another `Popup`, and it's template  has Popup inside (dropdown for selectable Items).

You must subscribe to events `MouseDownEvent` and `LostMouseCaptureEvent` and deal with mouse capturing for proper handling of `MouseDownEvent` outside of `Popup` control's area. Inspect and just copy some source code for your nested `ExtendedPopup`. You can inherit it from classical `Popup`.